# Select2 isn't showing properly inside a modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

My select2 works properly in one modal but not in another one. After posting the code I will explain the problem better.

This is the code of the modal where the select2 works fine

```
<div class="modal fade " id="modalAgendaCita" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAgendaCitaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalAgendaCitaLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="formCita">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="paciente" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Paciente') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control selection" id="paciente" name="paciente">
                                @if (isSet($personas))
                                    @foreach ($personas as $persona)
                                        <option value="{{ $persona->id}}">{{ $persona->nombre}} {{ $persona->apellido}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                    @else
                                    <option value="0">No existen pacientes</option>
                                @endif
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="especialidad" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Especialidad') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-control selection" id="especialidad" name="especialidad" required>
                                    @if (isSet($especialidades))
                                        @foreach ($especialidades as $especialidad)
                                            <option value="{{ $especialidad->id}}">{{ $especialidad->nombre}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                        @else
                                        <option value="0">No existen especialidades</option>
                                    @endif
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="medico" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Médico') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-control selection" id="medico" name="medico" required >
                                    <option value="0">No existen medico de esta especialidad</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fecha" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Fecha') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="fecha" type="date" readonly   class="form-control" min= new Date().toISOString.split('T')[]  @error('fecha') is-invalid @enderror name="fecha" required autocomplete="fecha" autofocus>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong id="errorFecha">@error('fecha') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="hora" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Hora') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="hora" readonly type="time" value="10:00" class="form-control" @error('hora') is-invalid @enderror name="hora" required autocomplete="hora" autofocus>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong id="errorHora">@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center text-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="AgendarCitas()">Agendar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the code of the modal where the select 2 is not working properly

```
<div class="modal fade " id="modalVerCita" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalVerCitaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalVerCitaLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="formCita2" >
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="paciente" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Paciente') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class ="form-control" id="paciente2" name="paciente" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if (Auth::user()->role === 'medico')
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="cedula" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Cédula') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class ="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Correo Electrónico') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class ="form-control" id="email" name="email" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="telefono" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Teléfono') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class ="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fecha3" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Fecha de nacimiento') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="fecha3" type="date"  readonly class="form-control" min= new Date().toISOString.split('T')[]  @error('fecha') is-invalid @enderror name="fecha3" required autocomplete="fecha" autofocus>
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong id="errorFecha">@error('fecha') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="especialidad" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Especialidad') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class ="form-control"  id="especialidad2" name="especialidad" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="medico" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Médico') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class ="form-control"  id="medico2" name="medico" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fecha" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Fecha') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="fecha2" type="date"  readonly class="form-control" min= new Date().toISOString.split('T')[]  @error('fecha') is-invalid @enderror name="fecha" required autocomplete="fecha" autofocus>
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong id="errorFecha">@error('fecha') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="hora" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Hora') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="hora2" type="time" value="10:00"  readonly class="form-control"  @error('hora') is-invalid @enderror name="hora" required autocomplete="hora" autofocus>
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong id="errorHora">@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if (Auth::user()->role === 'medico')
                        <div class="form-group row" style =display:none>
                            <label for="idCita" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('idCita') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class ="form-control" id="idCita" name="idCita" style =display:none readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h6>Datos de Consulta</h6>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sintomas" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Sintomas') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="sintomas" name="sintomas"> </textarea>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong id="errorHora">@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="tratamiento" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Tratamiento') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="tratamiento" name="tratamiento"> </textarea>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong id="errorHora">@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="diagnostico" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Diagnóstico') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="diagnostico" name="diagnostico"> </textarea>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong id="errorHora">@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fechaControl" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Fecha Proximo Control') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="fechaControl" type="date" readonly onfocus="abrirDatepicker(this)" class="form-control" min= new Date().toISOString.split('T')[]  @error('fecha') is-invalid @enderror name="fechaControl" required autocomplete="fechaControl" autofocus>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong id="errorFecha">@error('fecha') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="solExalemens" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Solicitar Examenes') }}</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2"></div>
                            <div class="form-check col">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="solicitaExamenes" id="solicitaExamenes1" value="si">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="solicitaExamenes1">
                                  Si
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check col">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="solicitaExamenes" id="solicitaExamenes" value="no" checked>
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="solicitaExamenes">
                                    No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content_detail_examen" style="display: none">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="detalles" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Detalles') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <textarea id="detalles" name="detalleExamen"> </textarea>
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong id="errorHora">@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tiposExamenes" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Tipos de Examenes') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control selection" id="tiposExamenes" name="tiposExamenes[]" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple" required>
                                        @if (isSet($tiposExamenes))
                                            @foreach ($tiposExamenes as $tiposExamene)
                                                <option value="{{ $tiposExamene->id}}">{{ $tiposExamene->nombre}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @else
                                            <option value="0">No existen tipos de examenes</option>
                                        @endif
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Receta') }}</label>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="medicamento_receta" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Medicamentos') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="medicamento_receta" name="medicamento_receta"> </textarea>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong id="errorMedicamento">@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="tratamiento_receta" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Tratamiento') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="tratamiento_receta" name="tratamiento_receta"> </textarea>
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong >@error('hora') {{ $message }} @enderror</strong>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center text-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        @if (Auth::user()->role === 'medico')
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonCancelar" onclick="Consulta()">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                        @elseif (Auth::user()->role === 'administrador')
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="botonCancelar" onclick="Cancelar()">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my JavaScript and CSS code that involves the select2

```
@section('css_extra')
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    .select2-container .select2-selection--single {
        height: 37px;
    }
</style>
@endsection
@section('js_extras')

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $('#especialidad').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#modalAgendaCita'),
        templateSelection: function (data) {
            changeSelector(data.id, null);
            return data.text
        }
    });
    $('#medico').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#modalAgendaCita'),
    });
    $('#tiposExamenes').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#modalVerCita'),
    });
```

I think thats all the code involved, sorry if it isnt all the code involved and I can post more code if necessary, I just don't want to have all the code of the view if not neccessary.

Both modal belong to the same blade file but the first one only shows when I click when there is no event in fullcalendar and the other one when I click into an event. The second one also shows more form fields when the role is 'medico' and this one has the select2 that doesn't work right.

The problem is that when I go to the second modal with the role 'medico' it shows in a wrong position like in the picture below.

[image: Image of select2 showing in wrong position]

In the other modal the select2 look fine like this

[image: Image of select2 working ok]

I'm new to web development and maybe I didn't post all the code that is needed but I can add all the necessary to solve the problem. Also if question is not worded properly english isn't my main language so sorry for any mistakes or I am not being clear enough.

As a sandbox was requested I'm going to post it

https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-sound-dex5l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The code of the modal that isnt working is in  resources/views/gestionCitas.blade.php

The database is the file that is called bd_hnf(8).sql and if you want to test the select2 you can access with this user

Username: D1301689752
Password: D1301689752

To reach the select2 go to Revisar Agenda after you log in and click in the blue event in the calendar, after that mark the radio of Solicitar Exámenes in option 'si'.

If the sandbox doesn't work sorry but I'm new using them or if you need any other info I can gladly provide it.

Comment: Do you mean the `medico` field is `disabled` after selection? Or when you select `medico`, its options are displayed in `sintomas`?

Comment: the select2 that isnt working good is this one  <select class="form-control selection" id="tiposExamenes" name="tiposExamenes[]" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple" required> This select 2 only shows inside the modal when the radio is selected in si (yes in spanish).  @HuyPhạm

Comment: and as you can see its showing way up of when it should appear. In the first modal paciente, especialidad and medico are select2 in the second modal only tipoExamenes is a select2 @HuyPhạm

Comment: is it possible for you to create a sample sandbox to see the problem getting reproduced?

Comment: how I can create a sandbox @bharat? also I get data from a local server so dunno if that would be possible to implement

Comment: may be out some dummy data

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more in dummy data please?

Comment: Hello. I'd suggest you posting a small reproducible version of your problem. People will generally not go through all of your code to find the problem for you, try to reproduce in jsfiddle or something like that :) Cheers